# pop() method of stack linked list using C has an error

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, stack

the problem is `printf()` in `pop()` method display the weird address and don't run anymore. the print result is below.

```
push (10)
push (20)
push (30)
push (40)
40
-842150451
```

Here's the entire code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;

node* head = NULL;

void init(){
    head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    head->data = 0;
    head->next = NULL;
}

void push(int data){

    node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(temp == NULL){
        printf("Out Of Memory");
    }else{
        head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data = data;
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
        printf("push (%d)\n", data);
    }
}

void pop(){
    node* temp;
    if(head == NULL) return;
    temp = head;
    printf("%d\n", head->data);
    head = head->next;
    free(temp);
}

void main(){

    push(10);
    push(20);
    push(30);
    push(40);

    pop();
    pop();
    pop();
    pop();
}
```

and this pop method doesn't work. 
It display 40 at first time.

and then print -842150451.
I don't get it why I receive this weird number.

```
void pop(){
    node* temp;
    if(head == NULL) return;
    temp = head;
    printf("%d\n", head->data);
    head = head->next;
    free(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a weird, extra malloc in `push()`, I got rid of it and things looked much better:

```
void push(int data) {

    node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Out Of Memory");
    } else {
        //head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));     <---- this is your problem
        temp->data = data;
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
        printf("push (%d)\n", data);
    }
}


push (10)
push (20)
push (30)
push (40)
40
30
20
10
```

Comment: Oh, gosh! So thank you! When I noticed my problem by your answer. I felt being stupid. I think I didn't understand the logic well. but now clear. so thank you!

Comment: Don't sweat it...dynamic memory can be a tricky concept at first, but it looks like you are getting the hang of it.